# Android code coverage in Jenkins CI

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, jacoco

I am using Gradle as a build automation tool for my Android project.
Jenkins CI runs my tests and generates a coverage report using the task `createDebugCoverageReport`.
Unfortunately I have not found a way to use the coverage.xml file that is generated within Jenkins CI.
I could publish the HTML report that is also generated, but that does not give me a trendline for the coverage.

Does anyone know how one could get a trendline for code coverage, when using the Android Gradle tools?

**Update:**
I've opened up an [issue on the related GitHub project](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/issues/49), and on the official JIRA for Jenkins CI ([issue #JENKINS-25616](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25616))